# Has there been studies done on changes in model performance post-crisis?

Tags: models, algorithm, financial-markets

My question is, has there been done any studies on whether the efficiency and accuracy of pricing and risk-management of derivatives using different models and algorithms has changed after the financial crisis of 2008? Both in absolute terms (i.e. do all algorithms perform better or worse than their previous levels) and in relative terms (i.e., has the performance gap between any two algorithms shrunk or increased?)

What particular model/algorithm it is and what particular purpose it has (pricing, hedging, calibrating to real world prices or vol-surfaces, whatever) is not really relevant. I am just interested in the study of whether the 'rules of thumb' that we used to have about our models and algorithms have changed since the crisis.